# Nofitication service not available in KDE plasma 5.19 after reboot

Tags: linux, notifications, plasma5, kde5

I rebooted my system and after logging in , I noticed that the notifications are no longer working correctly .In the notification widget the only thing appears is **Notifications are currently provided by `knobwobdunst`**.

Has anyone heard of that ?

Note that before I rebooted I had restarted the **plasma-shell** several times for some reasons (system uptime was about 17 days) but there was no problem.

I use KDE Neon 5.19 (based on ubuntu 18.04).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by unstalling dunst (re-install when needed).

On my machine, dunst and plasma default notification daemon have **same service name**.

***`cat /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.knopwob.dunst.service`***

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/bin/dunst
SystemdService=dunst.service
```

***`cat /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.kde.plasma.Notifications.service`***

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/usr/bin/plasma_waitforname org.freedesktop.Notifications
```

I got this comment from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/hgs41s/changing_the_notification_deamon/)

> Looks like the dbus just picks the first notification daemon present
> in the system when it receives a notification in the bus
> org.freedesktop.Notifications and ignores the others.

Links below might be helpful.

[Changing the notification deamon](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/hgs41s/changing_the_notification_deamon/)

[How do I disable Dunst and go back to notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092323/how-do-i-disable-dunst-and-go-back-to-notify-osd/1092324#1092324)